# .Find() Run-Time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, excel-2010

I know other questions have been asked with the same error but it's no where close to what I have. I am trying to find the row where I can find the value of the variable lab in column B multiple times with a loop(lab value change), it works the first time but second time I get this error.

```
For Each lab In arr    
    NFD = el & " " & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).value
    If SheetExists(NFD) Then

       Worksheets(NFD).Activate

       Dim FindRow As Range
       Dim FindRowNumber As Long
       Set FindRow = Sheets(NFD).Range("B:B").Find(What:=lab, LookIn:=xlValues)
       FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row 'error on this line

        MsgBox FindRowNumber

    End If
Next
```

EDIT1: This is the working code if anyone is interested:

```
For Each lab In arr
                If lab <> "" Then
                    lab = Trim(lab)
                        'Find element Sheet
                        NFD = el & " " & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 3).value
                            If SheetExists(NFD) Then    
                                'Find lab number row in colunm B
                              Set FindRow = Sheets(NFD).Range("B:B").Find(What:=lab, LookIn:=xlValues)

                               If FindRow Is Nothing Then
                                 Debug.Print "Nothing Found"
                               Else
                                  FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row

                               End If

                             End If

                End If

Next
```

Comment: Is the value you are trying to find in `Range("B:B")`? If not, I believe you will receive this error because you are trying to get the `.Row` property of an empty range.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it but I want to look if item is anywhere in column B

Comment: I'm surprised the system still allows for that title to exist

Comment: @phil652 What I mean is, if you hit Ctrl + F and search for the value stored in `item` in you procedure, is that value in `Range("B:B")`?

Comment: You omitted `LookAt:=xlPart` vs. `LookAt:=xlWhole`. Pick one and add it to your Find parameters so you are not relying on what was used in a Find the last time. Also never a good idea to use reserved words as variables. `Item` can mean a lot of things besides you var.

Comment: @Jeeped what would the find line be then?  `Set FindRow = Sheets(NFD).Range("B:B").Find(What:=item, LookAt:=xlWhole)` ?

Comment: @Kyle Yes at the time of the error item was = to 142. 142 is located at 144,B

Comment: Something like `.Find(What:=lab, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`

Comment: @Jeeped If I only change this line I get the same error but if I use your code with Sobigen answer I don't get any error but it can only find the first one. The other one are all Nothing Found even if they exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have to check if anything is found.  FindRow will be 'Nothing' if item isn't there.

```
If FindRow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing Found"
    'you can set FindRowNumber to something here if you want, like 0 or -1
Else
    FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
    MsgBox FindRowNumber
End If
```

Edit after the comment question
My test code is:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr(0 To 2) As String
    Dim lab As Variant
    Dim FindRow As Range
    Dim FindRowNumber As Long

    arr(0) = "aaa"
    arr(1) = "bbb"
    arr(2) = "ccc"

    For Each lab In arr
        Set FindRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Find(What:=lab, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If FindRow Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Nothing Found"
            'you can set FindRowNumber to something here if you want, like 0 or -1
        Else
            FindRowNumber = FindRow.Row
            Debug.Print FindRowNumber
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I had 'aaa', 'bbb' and 'ccc' in cells, B1, B2, and B3 respectively and it all worked as expected, printing 1, 2, and 3 in the debug console.

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner! If `.Find` doesn't find anything, `FindRow` is an empty range, and you can't access the `.Row` property of it.

Comment: If I use your code I don't get the error anymore. the msgbox is now "Nothing Found" every time except the first time but the value exist. Any idea why?

Comment: I added my test code to the answer.  How does it compare to your implementation?

Comment: @Sobigen Thank you for your time! I just posted more code. I think I found the issue. Since my cell is in this format `108, 142, 150`. It work the first time because it's looking for "108" but the second time it's looking for " 142". Now I need to figure out how to remove the space

Comment: @phil652 Try using the `TRIM(string_to_trim)` function

Comment: @user3561813 This is what I need, it now works perfecly. Thanks!

Comment: @Sobigen Thank you very much for you answer, it works perfectly. All I had to do was add Trim to lab. I posted the working code in my question if you are interested.